# Is there a term used when internal variables are declared public and accessible?

Tags: terminology, scope

If someone writes code so that an internal variable $_fields is accessible without using getter/setter methods, is there a proper term used to describe that?

Something polite enough to use with management :)

Comment: Lack of encapsulation?

Comment: @Oded I think you're right - lack of/poor encapsulation describes it well

Comment: The two phrases I thought of while trying to answer this question were "leaky abstraction" and "loose scoping" - what do each of those refer to (outside my head)?

Comment: Leaky abstraction is when you try to abstract a concept but it doesn't really work - the underlying concepts still leak out (ORMs over SQL and web frameworks over HTTP/HTML tend to be leaky abstractions).

Comment: @PeterB - to add to Oded's explanation, see this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: Russian coders sometimes say _Public Morozov_ at unnecessarily wide access modifiers, alluding to a story about improper information disclosure and further punishment caused by that ([Pavlik Morozov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavlik_Morozov))

Comment: @gnat, *public Morozov* is a more specific pattern, when a child class grants public access to the protected members of its parent. :) (which is what Pavlik Morozov did)

Comment: Indecent exposure?

Comment: @Rotsor As far as I know your interpretation is considered most accurate indeed. However I also heard it used more loosely _just expose everything to anyone_ - likely referring to idea that for legendary Pavlik it didn't really matter _whom_ to expose. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Exposing ones private members is never a good thing in polite society...

This practice is the lack of/poor encapsulation.

Comment: +1, Well, you wouldn't get _your_ privates out in the office would you?

Comment: @StuperUser - Dont ask a question you dont want the answer to! ;)

Comment: -1: Encapsulation really did happen and happened well.  But it wasn't **documented** through the source code in the commonly accepted way.  Some languages (like Python) lack truly private variables, yet still practice encapsulation.

Comment: @S.Lott - In most modern languages, this _would_ be considered breaking encapsulation. What would you call this in languages that allow private members?

Comment: @Oded: Encapsulation is a design *concept*.  Different languages have different implementations of the concept.  A language with a private declaration permits one implementation.  A functional programming language with stateless objects might have a different implementation.  Python (which lacks `private`) has yet another implementation of the concept of encapsulation.

Comment: I hate when my privates get exposed, especially when compression is enabled.

Comment: @S Lott ; Oded - Encapsulation is good and relying on code where private variables are frequently directly accessed from other classes is poor encapsulation.  In python, you do this by accessing name-mangled private variables of another class or ignoring conventions of a single underscore prefix (though if your getter is doing other behavior; really should use `__` for name mangling).  Other languages can have poor encapsulation too, e.g., reflection in Java and pointer arithmetic in C++ to get at private variables.  Python just doesn't make the syntax to do it that cumbersome.

Comment: Dogmatism is rarely a good thing and "never" is a very strong word.  Never say never, just, rarely :-)

Comment: @drjimbob: Python code rarely uses `__` name mangling.  Without the `__`, it the design still reflects good encapsulation.  Claiming that "public" means "lack of/poor encapsulation" is wrong.  The concept is still present.  The source code lacks appropriate decoration.

Comment: @SLott - I do not think we disagree.  Public means poor encapsulation only if the variable should be accessed by a class's functions (e.g., getters and setters are keeping something invariant). In python you should use the private access specifier by the `_` or `__` prefix in the name for encapsulation.  If your code frequently uses internal variables marked private when better alternatives exist, that's poor encapsulation.  I do agree that's its a waste to write trivial getters/setters for every member variable when they aren't needed (no side effects from accessing/modifying).

Answer (score 10):

Besides the lack of encapsulation already mentioned by Oded, depending on the programming language and its paradigms it could also be ["plain old data"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) (where it isn't necessarily an antipattern or code smell).

Answer (score 4):

I've heard the term "naked object" before.

Comment: It is certainly a confusing way to name those considering the [Naked Objects Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_objects)

Comment: Yeah, that got me confused as well.

Answer (score 2):

Its called a property bag.

Usually it is used to hold a set of maybe related properties (were each may potentially be a class object that has appropriate access specifiers or not). But the surrounding structure is just a bag of properties.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "not following a specific coding standard".

The OP wrote:

> an internal variable $_fields is accessible without using getter/setter methods

That might be against your standard, and (thus) it might be code smell. But it is *not necessarily* poor encapsulation. Exposing an internal (as in "only of internal use") variable over getter and setters to the outside world would be even worse.

The question is: should `$_fields` be accessible for the outside world?

If so, we have a case where you would add getter/setter methods. These methods do not encapsulate anything but the fact that `$_fields` is a variable of some kind (as opposed to something calculated/fetched/etc. on the fly). Depending on the language, you'll probably still leak the type (aka an implementation detail) to the outside. Whether you always want getters/setters, or only when "needed" is a coding standard issue.

If `$_fields` should *not* be accessible, then, well, don't access it. Whether you should keep others from accessing it on the language level (private and friends) or not (which might ease debugging in certain circumstances) is - again - a coding standard issue.

The issue of encapsulation is entirely orthogonal to this. Violating encapsulation is absolutely possible with getters and setters. It's even *easier* to slip into, because most people's alarm bells don't ring when they see a bunch of getters and setters - code that's seemingly following best practices. Code, that might very well introduce much more dependencies on internal implementation details than a variable called `$_fields` that happens not to be specified as `private`.

I'm a fan of bad analogies: Calling that poor encapsulation is like calling someone who holds a gun a murderer.

Answer (score 1):

I would call such variables **public member variables**.

Answer (score -2):

if your setter/getter methods are nothing more than

```
void setfoo(bar){foo=bar;}
foo getfoo{return foo;}
```

then just making a pubic variable is just saving some typing outside of a few edge cases where the difference matters.

Comment: Just because that's all your getters and setters do now doesn't mean that's the way it'll always be. And if adding validation to a setter requires combing through tens of thousands of lines of code to find everywhere that property is accessed, you'll instantly blow the dozen seconds you saved yourself by purposely avoiding encapsulation the first time.

Comment: @Plutor: If that's all the object will ever do (e.g., because it represents a message sent to another process or a record in a database) then it's OK; those are things that _should_ be highly conserved.